# calulate according to the DOB given

Tags: ruby

I made student list containing roll no.,name, gender, DOB,Age ,marks1,marks2,marks3,total and avg.
i want to right a code for age 
that is when i click on age it should display the correct age according to the DOB given.
can you help using textbox events in c#

Comment: Maybe you made a mistake, but your question is related to C#, while you marked the question with a "ruby" flag.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should be

`ageInYears = currentYear - birthYear - (birthMonth <= currentMonth && birthDay <= currentDay ? 0 : 1);`

Subtract the years, and subtract an additional year if they haven't had their birthday yet this year.